# Taking mean of means of groups

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe with several columns and several rows. I would like to group by a column called "A". I can do this by `df.groupby('A')`. Now I would like to take the means of column called "C" of each group which I can do with `df.groupby('A').C.mean()`. Finally, I would like to take the mean of the means of each group for column C.

How can I achieve this (the final result should just be one integer, i.e. the mean of the means of each group)?

Comment: Can you give some *minimal* data (input + output) to both demonstrate what you want? This will also help us check our solution is in line with your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another mean:

```
df.groupby('A').C.mean().mean()
```